# Why can't size_t be directly compared with negative int?

Tags: c++

One bug in my program is caused by directly comparing `size_t` with `int`.

A toy sample code is as follows:

```
string s = "AB";
cout << (-1 < 8888888+(int)s.size()) << endl;
cout << (-1 < 8888888+s.size()) << endl;
```

The output is:

> 1
>
> 0

So why can't `size_t` be directly compared with negative `int`?

Comment: `size_t` is unsigned. How would you compare that to a negative value?

Comment: Oh I got it! Thanks! I will modify my question before someone got angry. :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`size_t` is unsigned, and can thus only express positive numbers. Comparing it to a negative will have wacky results.

If you try casting the `int` (-1) as a `size_t`, you'll find that it becomes an enormous number, which explains the behavior you are having.

Answer (score 5):

Because `size_t` is unsigned and `int` is signed. Language has special rules for such "mixed" comparisons, as well as for "mixed" arithmetic. In this case these rules say that everything should be converted to `size_t`. Conversion to `size_t`, which is unsigned, distorts the original value of the `int` rather drastically (`-1` becomes `SIZE_MAX`), which is what causes the "strange" result in the second case.

In the first case you forcefully convert `size_t` to `int`, thus turning your comparison into `int` vs. `int` one. It behaves in expected fashion.

Note, BTW, that `std::string::size()` returns `std::string::size_type`, which is an unsigned type, but not necessarily `size_t`.

Comment: It's a shame they chose this direction.  Because size_t is usually a small integer, so the less surprising implicit cast would be (signed) size > -1, rather than size > (unsigned) -1

Comment: @AlanBaljeu In today's (manybits) world, size_t should have been signed. As you say, it usually is a small integer.