# Why is "-1 < strlen(s)" equal to 0?

Tags: c, integer, implicit-conversion, comparison-operators, strlen

```c
char* s =(char*) "sss";
int j = -1;
printf("%d", j < strlen(s));
```

It's mainly about the difference between `j < 3` and `j < strlen(s)`.

In the above code, the `printf()` function prints 0, but if I change `strlen(s)` to 3, the result becomes 1 (just as what I expect).

What is the cause?

Comment: Have a look at the [definition](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strlen) of `strlen`; it returns a `size_t`. As `size_t` is *unsigned* and `-1` is an `int` constant, signed and of smaller size than `size_t`, it is promoted to `size_t` as well. This promotion yields the maximum value of `size_t`, which is never smaller than any other possible value...

Comment: A good compiler should have issued a warning about comparing signed and unsigned values, didn't do so yours?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can't size\_t be directly compared with negative int?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35901353/why-cant-size-t-be-directly-compared-with-negative-int)

Comment: Enable your compiler's warnings. With gcc, I use `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`. It would have caught this problem.

Answer (score 8):

The return type of `strlen` is `size_t`, which is an unsigned integer type.  When comparing a `size_t` to an `int`, the "usual arithmetic conversions" are applied.  In this case, that means the `int` operand, i.e. `-1`, is converted to a `size_t`, resulting in the largest possible `size_t` value, which is greater than the `strlen` value.

Comment: @SergeBallesta Isn't conversion from signed to unsigned defined as adding maximum value + 1 as long as the number remains negative? That should be fine for other representations as well, but for 2C it has the nice advantage that bit patterns are identical.

Comment: @SergeBallesta C23 will require 2's complement. Unless you're into working with hardware from the 1970's or older, there's not much point in considering other representations of signed integers

Comment: Pedantic: "In this case, that means the int operand, i.e. -1, is converted to a size_t" --> Yes that is by far the common case, yet the reverse occurs when `int` range exceed `size_t`.

Answer (score 4):

In this expression

```
j < strlen(s)
```

the compiler at first determines the common type of the expression to perform the operation using the usual arithmetic conversions.

The type of the expression `strlen( s )` is unsigned integer type `size_t` that usually is defined as an alias for the type `unsigned long`.

From the C Standard (**6.3.1.8 Usual arithmetic conversions**):

> Otherwise, if the operand that has unsigned integer type has rank
> greater or equal to the rank of the type of the other operand, then
> the operand with signed integer type is converted to the type of the
> operand with unsigned integer type. See the declaration of the
> function `strlen`

```
size_t strlen(const char *s);
^^^^^^
```

As the rank of the type `size_t` is greater than the rank of the signed type `int` then the left operand of the comparison operator is converted to the type `size_t` propagating the sign bit. As a result you get a very big unsigned value.

Try for example this call of printf

```
printf( "( size_t )-1 = %zu\n", ( size_t )-1 );
```

Comment: ... or `unsigned long long` on those 64-bit systems where `unsigned long` remained 32 bits – namely 64-bit Windows...